# Pure Data MIDI Toggle Switch

Tags: puredata

I am looking to build a tool that allows me to toggle on/off certain GEMheads in my patch based on MIDI pad input. Pressing one pad would turn on a render chain and pressing a different pad would activate a new render chain.  Pressing the midi pad for any active render chain should disable the rendering.

I'm having quite some trouble building this into my current patches which look like this:

[pad_control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHcw2.png) 
[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgXvN.png)

I grab the MIDI identity and use it to generate a one or a zero, however I'm not certain of the logic to keep the output as a 1 when pressing different MIDI pads and how to add the toggle functionality.  As of now, only one can be active at any given time.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Generally, what you want is something that turns the pad input 0 (while no input) and 1 (while being hold down) into a toggle, that switches back between the two states 0 and 1 each time the pad is pressed. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that's right! I'm interested both in having only input while the MIDI is held down as well as having a single press of the MIDI pad toggle between the two states

Comment: So that's maybe multiple questions in one? I'd recommend to break it down and ask each individual question in a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's basically what you are after, the toggle representing the MIDI pad. The `change` object is only there to protect for cases like with a keyboard, where repeated strokes are sent, probably not necessary for a MIDI pad, but doesn't hurt either.

[image]

Comment: You can accept this answer as solving your question, or upvote it if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

For those wondering, this is what my solution looks like tuned specifically to my MIDI settings

[controller_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnEgr.png)

Hope this helps anyone else!

Comment: Oh, please do it like this, and then read about abstractions. http://imgur.com/a/pkH8s

Comment: The fanning connection from the number box into the spigot is asking for trouble.